# Calling java -jar command using AWS lambda steps

Tags: aws-lambda

I have 4 shell scripts which I embedded in java code and converted into jar. I also have a lambda AWS function which brings up the EMR cluster. In lambda function, I should run the generated jar (java -jar /home/hadoop/aws.jar) using steps. I have bootstrap actions where I am setting few environmental variables when the cluster is bought up. So ideally, after the cluster is up the cluster should run the java -jar command which was specified in steps values in json events.
But the problem is **the emr is terminating failing in the step jar command**. Is there any other way to run the java -jar command from lambda using steps.

```
    "Steps":[
        {
            "Name": "Setup hadoop debugging",
            "ActionOnFailure": "TERMINATE_CLUSTER",
            "HadoopJarStep": {
                "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
                "Args": [
                    "state-pusher-script"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "Name": "Execute Step JAR",
            "ActionOnFailure": "TERMINATE_CLUSTER",
            "HadoopJarStep": {
                "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
                "Args":[
                    "java -jar /home/hadoop/lib/aws-add-step-emr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar"
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "BootstrapActions":[
        {
            "Name": "Custom action",
            "ScriptBootstrapAction": {
                "Path": "s3://aws-east-1/bootstrap/init.sh"
            }
        }]
```